# Select columns based on count of many-to-many association

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres database with 3 tables that looks a little something like this:

```
table categories
 id
 type

table games
 id

table game_category
 id
 game_id
 category_id
```

I want to select all `games` which have more than x `categories` where `type` is `something`

I have gotten this far:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE id IN (
  SELECT game_id FROM game_category GROUP BY game_id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
)
```

This works to select all games with more than 5 categories, but doesn't narrow down the categories by their type. How could I expand on this to add the additional check for the type?

Comment: `SELECT game_id FROM game_category gc inner join categories c on c.id = gc.category_id GROUP BY game_id WHERE type = 'X' HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5`

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks! Unfortunately that does not work I'm getting `syntax error at or near "WHERE"`, which points to the `WHERE` before `type = 'X'`.

Comment: Sorry, the entire `where` clause should have been before the `group by`. That was my attempt to start with your original query. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join your categories table with the subquery. Then you can add a `WHERE` clause for the type. Replace `'?'` with your actual type, of course.

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE id IN (
  SELECT game_id FROM game_category 
  INNER JOIN categories ON (categories.id=game_category.category_id)
  WHERE categories.type='?'
  GROUP BY game_id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering query response time, you can avoid the in  clause. Mitchel's answer would work if written as follows:

SELECT game_id
FROM game_category gc
inner join categories c on c.id = gc.category_id
WHERE type = 'X'
GROUP BY game_id
HAVING COUNT(game_id) >= 5

Notice I avoided using count(*) that is also a query optimization strategy

Comment: While this does work to select the correct `game_category`s, it doesn't actually select the `game` itself. I went with the solution provided by Guillaume.